# Android BLE: descriptor/characteristic write fails with GATT_WRITE_NOT_PERMITTED

Tags: java, android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

From my mobile device(scanner) I am trying to write to a descriptor in a connected wearable(broadcaster).

on the wearable, I have defined the descriptor as

```
readCharacteristic = new BluetoothGattCharacteristic(Constants.READ_CHAR_UUID,
                            BluetoothGattCharacteristic.PROPERTY_READ | BluetoothGattCharacteristic.PROPERTY_NOTIFY,
                            BluetoothGattCharacteristic.PERMISSION_READ);
readCharacteristic.addDescriptor(new BluetoothGattDescriptor(Constants.NOTIFY_DESC_UUID,
                        BluetoothGattDescriptor.PERMISSION_READ | BluetoothGattDescriptor.PERMISSION_WRITE));
```

on the mobile, I try to write to the characteristic with

```
BluetoothGattDescriptor descriptor = readCharacteristic.getDescriptor(Constants.NOTIFY_DESC_UUID);
descriptor.setValue(BluetoothGattDescriptor.ENABLE_NOTIFICATION_VALUE)
```

Unfortunately, this fails with status GATT_WRITE_NOT_PERMITTED in

```
@Override
public void onDescriptorWrite(BluetoothGatt gatt, BluetoothGattDescriptor descriptor, int status) {

}
```

In the wearable logcat I see gatts_write_attr_perm_check - GATT_WRITE_NOT_PERMIT.

The same thing happens when I try to write to a characteristic.

What is weird is that the write succeeds when using an iOS scanner. This means that the wearable part is correct.

I have the permissions in the Manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
```

Devices used:
Nexus 5x 6.0.1 API 23,
Moto 360 5.1.1 API 22

Does anyone have an idea how to fix this descriptor/characteristic write issue?

Answer (score 1):

> From my mobile device(scanner) I am trying to write to a descriptor in
>   a connected wearable(broadcaster).

In this case it should be mobile device(central) and connected wearable(peripheral). scanner and broadcaster does not establish BLE connection actually.

Regarding to the write failure, it was reject at the function `gatts_write_attr_perm_check` when application try to write data to database. the code just like below:

```
else if (!(perm & GATT_WRITE_ALLOWED))
      {
          status = GATT_WRITE_NOT_PERMIT;
          GATT_TRACE_ERROR( "gatts_write_attr_perm_check -GATT_WRITE_NOT_PERMIT");
       }
```

So, the problem is the recorded perm was not eligible with GATT_WRITE_ALLOWED，  which is

```
> (GATT_PERM_WRITE | GATT_PERM_WRITE_ENCRYPTED |\
> GATT_PERM_WRITE_ENC_MITM |  GATT_PERM_WRITE_SIGNED |\
> GATT_PERM_WRITE_SIGNED_MITM)
```

So, could you have a following try:
1) unpair the device and pair the device again.
2) enable the high security level e.g. enable the MITM.

And I assume you want to enable the notification right? I could not get all the code you have but can you also try this(quote from Android website):

```
private BluetoothGatt mBluetoothGatt;
BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic;
boolean enabled;
...
mBluetoothGatt.setCharacteristicNotification(characteristic, enabled);
...
BluetoothGattDescriptor descriptor = characteristic.getDescriptor(
        UUID.fromString(SampleGattAttributes.CLIENT_CHARACTERISTIC_CONFIG));
descriptor.setValue(BluetoothGattDescriptor.ENABLE_NOTIFICATION_VALUE);
mBluetoothGatt.writeDescriptor(descriptor);
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried with PERMISSION_WRITE_SIGNED_MITM on the descriptor but now when trying to write to it I get status 1 on onDescriptorWrite. I guess its GATT_FAILURE = 0x101? Do you have any other ideas what might help?

Comment: sorry is their any log?

Comment: I also edited the post; if you are trying to enable the notification,  just follow the sample.

Comment: did you ever try to with different devices except the wearable device? and did you tried different apps, e.g. use lightblue app on iOS to connect with your wearable device?

Comment: if I use iOS app as the peripheral then the Android central is working

Comment: This is exactly how I'm enabling the notification, unfortunately in onDescriptorWrite I do not get status == BluetoothGatt.GATT_SUCCESS, but status == 1.
In wear log there is nothing special imo http://pastebin.com/YDri9pWD.

Comment: strange; the status == 1 may means GATT_INVALID_HANDLE. did you try take iOS app as central and your wearable device as peripheral?

Comment: yes it works when iOS is the central and wearable the peripheral

Comment: then their something wrong with you apps? did you tried other android phones to avoid the bluetooth stack version issue